# One x-axis category not appearing on bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following code. I would like to blot a bar chart, with the x-axis labels 'never','former','current', as specified in the 'smoking number' column of the 'newdata' dataframe.

However, when I run the code, only 2 of 3 bars appear on the bar chart. I am not sure as to why this is.

Additionally, the standard error bars are also not appearing.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.2)
 
newdata = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').mean().reset_index()
sem = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').sem().reset_index()
newdata['smoking-number'] = newdata['smoking-number'].map({1: 'never', 2: 'former', 3: 'current'})
print(newdata)
newdata.plot.bar(x='smoking-number',y='distance', yerr= sem, ax=axes[0],legend=False)
newdata.plot.bar(x='smoking-number',y='duration', yerr= sem, ax=axes[1],legend=False)
upperbounddistance = max(newdata[['distance']].values)+max(sem[['distance']].values)
lowerbounddistance = min(newdata[['distance']].values)-min(sem[['distance']].values)
upperboundduration = max(newdata[['duration']].values)+max(sem[['duration']].values)
lowerboundduration = min(newdata[['duration']].values)-min(sem[['duration']].values)
axes[0].set_ylim(lowerbounddistance,upperbounddistance)
axes[0].set_xlim(0.5,3.5)
axes[1].set_ylim(lowerboundduration,upperboundduration)
axes[1].set_xlim(0.5,3.5)
axes[0].set_ylabel("Wayfinding distance")
axes[0].set_xlabel("Smoking frequency")
axes[1].set_ylabel("Wayfinding duration")
axes[1].set_xlabel("Smoking frequency")
```

[image]

I would be so grateful if anybody could give me a helping hand?

First 10 lines of newdf 'smoking-number column', 'duration' and 'distance columns':

```
distance
10  48.146090
13  98.877301
17  66.670310
19  95.764316
21  78.737108
22  48.404197
25  63.910073
27  40.862231
28  50.223985
30  38.724922
```

```
duration
10  40.976006
13  90.093298
17  88.349603
19  82.737323
21  72.579054
22  40.059987
25  57.629693
27  38.419589
28  40.834470
30  34.813547
```

```
smoking-number
10  1.0
13  1.0
17  1.0
19  1.0
21  1.0
22  1.0
25  3.0
27  1.0
28  1.0
30  1.0
```

Comment: The formula `lowerbounddistance = min(newdata[['distance']].values)-min(sem[['distance']].values)` looks very strange.  Did you try `lowerbounddistance = 0`? Maybe `min(sem[['distance']].values` is zero, making one of the bars invisible?

Comment: When I set the minimal value on the Y-axis to 0, the 3rd bar chart still doesn't appear, and none of the standard error bars are appearing on the bars either, but not sure why? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Well, without knowing your data, how do you expect someone else to know what you're doing? Note that this kind of plot might be simpler via seaborn, as it automatically does the grouping and calculates means and error bars.  E.g. `sns.barplot(newdf, x='smoking-number', y='distance', ax=axes[0])`.

Comment: @JohanC thank you for your suggestion I will try this out :) I have also amended the post above to include some data.

Comment: In your example data, there aren't values for `former`, so maybe its mean is undefined? Is there a reason you didn't check the calculated values?

Comment: @JohanC, the string 'former' replaced the number 2 in the original data - I have managed to find a way to make it work by using Seaborn :)